# How to define the return type of currying function?

Tags: typescript

I have a currying function that looks as follows:

```
export interface NewIdeaCardSubmit {
    title: string,
    description: string,
    categories: CategoryValues
}

const applyInputs = (title: string) =>
                    (description: string) =>
                    (categories: CategoryValues) => {
                       return ({
                           title: title,
                           description: description,
                           categories: categories
                       } as NewIdeaCardSubmit )
                    };
```

Is there another way to define the return type of `applyInputs` function instead of with `as`?

Nice would be:

```
const applyInputs = (title: string) => (description: string) => (categories: CategoryValues) => NewIdeaCardSubmit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This's the one you need?

````
export interface NewIdeaCardSubmit {
    title: string,
    description: string,
    categories: CategoryValues
}

const applyInputs = (title: string) =>
                    (description: string) =>
                    (categories: CategoryValues): NewIdeaCardSubmit => 
                       ({
                           title: title,
                           description: description,
                           categories: categories
                       })```
````

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps first define the function type:

```
export interface NewIdeaCardSubmit {
    title: string,
    description: string,
    categories: number[]
}
type ApplyInputs = (title: string) => (description: string) => (categories: number[]) => NewIdeaCardSubmit;
const applyInputs2: ApplyInputs = (title) => (description) => (categories) => ({ title: title, description: description, categories: categories })
```